# ec2 error starting instances insufficient capacity

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, vpc, availability-zone

We have created an AWS EC2 instance in Asia Pacific (Mumbai) region on Shared Hardware rental type. We are trying to start an instance after shut down and we are getting pop up error stating instances insufficient capacity message on screen. On white papers, it is mentioned like this, Try to launch new EC2 instance but as we have basic plan, it is not allowing us to create new instance on another zone.

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the **exact** error message. Are you using LightSail? What do you mean by "basic plan"?

Comment: Goes without saying, but sometimes a good hard refresh also does the trick

Answer (score 29):

According to the documentation, getting an `InsufficientInstanceCapacity` error when launching or restarting an instance means that Amazon does not have enough capacity to serve your request. There are a few options:

- Waiting for a while and trying again
- Launching an instance without specifying an availability zone
- Changing the instance type

You can read more [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/troubleshooting-launch.html#troubleshooting-launch-capacity).

Answer (score 2):

Below are a few options available

- Wait for that instance type to become available.
- Launch a different instance type.
- Launch an instance in a different availability zone and migrate back at a later time, if necessary. This provides a temporary solution until you can replace it at a later time with one in the desired availability zone. However, you will be charged cross-zone data transfer costs.
- Launch an instance in the -Any- availability zone
- Purchase a reserved instance (for that instance type) in the desired availability zone. This will also prevent you from receiving this error in the future.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually caused by
AWS not having enough available On-Demand capacity to complete your request.

1. For troubleshooting steps, see [1].
2. If the preceding troubleshooting steps don't resolve the problem, then you can move the instance to another VPC or to another subnet and Availability Zone[2].

Tip :
To avoid insufficient capacity errors on critical machines, consider using
On-Demand Capacity Reservations[3].

To use an On-Demand Capacity Reservation, do the following :

```
1. Create the Capacity Reservation[4] in an Availability Zone.

2. Launch critical instances into your Capacity Reservation[5].
```

Reference :
[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/troubleshooting-launch.html#troubleshooting-launch-capacity

[2] https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/move-ec2-instance/

[3] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-capacity-reservations.html

[4] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/capacity-reservations-using.html#capacity-reservations-create

[5] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/capacity-reservations-using.html#capacity-reservations-launch

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to AWS, there's usually a limit for how many instances can you launch or start even if you are currently running none. Try to request for a limit increase for the instance you want to launch in the support center and the insufficient capacity error will disappear